# How to convert ArrayList into int

Tags: c#

I have some really simple code:

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
int var1 = 10;
int var2;

array.Add(var1);
var2 = array[0];
```

and Visual Studio is showing an error, as I expected:

> Cannot implicitly convert type object to int....

I know that I can use explicit conversion, like this one:

```
var2 = (int)array[0];
```

or

```
var2 = Convert.ToInt32(array[0]);
```

I found this question on some quiz, and unfortunately, those 2 answers weren't offered, and as correct answer they have marked:

```
var2 = ((List<int>)array)[0];
```

I've tested this solution, and there is another error in VS.

Am I missing something, or did they just make a mistake marking that answer as correct?

Comment: Why an ArrayList? Can't u just use a List<int>?

Comment: Well, I've found this question in this form , so I assume that it is important to stay ArrayList

Comment: `ArrayList` is outdated, look for newer material.

Comment: "The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance." [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why are you adding the value of an int to an `ArrayList` and then assigning it to another variable? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I dont understand. where did you see this? share the link plz and i will kill the guy who said that ;)

Comment: Ok guys , don't shoot the messenger :D This is question for preparation for some MS exam.

Comment: We're just wondering that's all. As @HenkHolterman said, you should look for new material to learn from.

Comment: There have been some tweaks with the very limited support for co- and contravariance in early C# but I don't think that casting ArrayList to `List<int>` was ever legal. So yes, this was a wrong 'correct' answer.

Answer (score -1):

I tried `((List<int>)array)` and VS throws the following exception.

```
Compilation error (line 16, col 17): Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'
```

So, I concur with you the marked answer is not correct.

Also, want to know that was there any option with case like

```
var2 = array.Cast<int>().First();
```

Answer (score -1):

There is error with your code ...
you can convert Array List items  to Generic List and then can select any item from that Generic Collection .
here is correct code

```
 var2= ((List<int>)array[0])[0];
```

Comment: The error was already mentioned in the question. Did you test this?

Comment: You won't be able to cast an `int` to a `List<int>` no matter how hard you try.

Comment: Unhandled exception is thrown, I've tested it .